# how to build a pipeline using perl

Tags: perl, wait, pipeline

I would like to run a series of system command using perl. I wrote a for loop

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
foreach my $ichr (1 .. 21){
    system "bedtools intersect -wb -a genes.bed -b chr$ichr.bed > Counts_chr$ichr.txt";
}
```

I am not sure whether the loop will submit each command to the system and start the next one? I want one to finish before it starts the next one. (e.g., finish chr1, then start chr2, finish chr2, then start chr3 . etc)

How can i make sure that one command finished and then start the next one?

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
perldoc -f system
```

> ```
>            Does exactly the same thing as "exec LIST", except that a fork
>            is done first and the parent process waits for the child
>            process to exit.
> ```

So the `system` command will wait for the started process to finish before it continues the next loop iteration.

Comment: great. I have a follow up question. Is this only applicaple to commands that are in a for loop? What if i have two system commands which are not in for loop and I need to wait for the first one to finish and then run the second one (basically i would like to build a pipeline and need first system command to finish before perl submit the next system command).

Comment: The documentation that was quoted to you says nothing at all about a for loop. Therefore it's reasonable to assume that the behaviour described has nothing to do with for loops :-)

Comment: When the system call start the run the subprocess it suspends the perl process, and it will continue when the subprocess exits. So the system commands will be processed one-by-one.

Comment: I was confused with the concept of parent and child fork process. I don't know what it means. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18760891/please-explain-fork